# How do i generate 1800 rps in locust, from one locustfile?

Tags: python, load-testing, locust

I have a locustfile, which is for generating load for a certain target website.
In my case i need to crate 1800 rps. but i am not able to generate that much in the single locustfile.

So i have created 4 locust file and generate 450 rps for each. but the rps not give as my expectation. It was dropped and became as very low.

Answer (score 0):

You can run the same locustfile as master/worker setup where you start a worker for each core you have on your machine.

Comment: In every 5 min RPS value drops, my locust version is 0.7.5

Comment: Your version is about 4 years old. Start by upgrading. Next, check that the bottleneck is not your target: check the response times when the throughput drops (if they are increasing then congratulations: you have most likely found a bottleneck/problem in your target system :)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to switch to a SaaS software in order to generare that many requests, such as https://rungutan.com